# How Spring close ApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring

I have spring web application and I need to reload new application.properties at run time. For me is important to finish all current task.  My code is:

```
public void restartSpringApplication() {
    ApplicationArguments args = applicationContext.getBean(ApplicationArguments.class);
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        applicationContext.close();
        applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(springBootClassHolder.getClazz(), args.getSourceArgs());
    });

    thread.setDaemon(false);
    thread.start();
}
```

Is this code safety? If some transaction is in process, so it wait until transaction  will done or it kill transaction?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a different property source/mechanism so you won't need to reload the ApplicationContext?

Comment: why not just restart the app in this case?